# Using Python, how to download multiple files from a subdirectory on FTP server into a desired directory on local machine?

Tags: python, ftplib, chdir

Using python program, I was able to download multiple source files from a FTP server (using `ftplib` and `os` libraries) to my local machine.

These source file resides at a particular directory inside the FTP server.

I was able to download the source files only if I have provided the same directory path in my local machine, as of FTP directory path.

I am able to download the files into `C:\data\abc\transfer` which is same as remote directory `/data/abc/transfer`. Code is insisting me to provide the same directory.

But I want to download all files into my desired directory `C:\data_download\`

Below is the code :

```
import ftplib
import os
from ftplib import FTP

Ftp_Server_host = 'xcfgn@wer.com'
Ftp_username ='qsdfg12'
Ftp_password = 'xxxxx'
Ftp_source_files_path = '/data/abc/transfer/'

ftp = FTP(Ftp_Server_host)
ftp.login(user=Ftp_username, passwd=Ftp_password)
local_path = 'C:\\data_download\\'
print("connected to remote server :" + Ftp_Server_host)
print()
ftp_clnt = ftp_ssh.open_sftp()
ftp_clnt.chdir(Ftp_source_files_path)
print("current directory of source file in remote server :" +ftp_clnt.getcwd())
print()

files_list = ftp.nlst(Ftp_source_files_path)
for file in files_list:
    print("local_path :" + local_path)
    local_fn = os.path.join(local_path)
    print(local_fn)
    print('Downloading files from remote server :' + file)
    local_file = open (local_fn, "wb")
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file, local_file.write)
    local_file.close()
    print()

print("respective files got downloaded")
print()
ftp_clnt.close()
```

[image: original output]

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a full path to `open` function, not just a directory name.

To assemble a full local path, take a file name from the remote paths returned by `ftp.nlst` and combine them with the target local directory path.

Like this:

```
local_fn = os.path.join(local_path, os.path.basename(file))
```

Comment: it worked thank you so much.. the code ran successful and results are satisfactory ..thank you once again.